# Why is Root Namespace automatically included

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, compilation

A colleague of mine just came across a strange compiler quirk, where it is importing what seems like the "root" namespace.

The issue is that when we add a reference to a shared library, which has a namespace of `Root.Security`, it complains in every file that the class `Root.Entity.X` is used (even though it does not have `using Root` or `using Root.Security`.

Example

### `Root.Entities` Assembly

`Security.cs`

```
namespace Root.Entities
{
    public class Security { } // Represents a Security in the sense of financial instrument
}
```

### `Root.Security` Assembly

This assembly has Active Directory + Permission shared helpers,

`SecurityHelper.cs`

```
namespace Root.Security
{
    public class SecurityHelper { } // AD/Permission helper
}
```

### `Root.Gui` Assembly

`Main.cs`

```
using Root.Entities;

namespace Root.Gui
{
    public class Main
    {
        public Main()
        {
            // The following causes an error 
            // if Root.Security is add as a reference to the project.
            // even without adding `using Root.Security`
            var security = new Security();
        }
    }
}
```

### Question

My question is, why is the compiler throwing the error and picking the `Security` up as a namespace, even though we do not have `using Root` or `using Root.Security` anywhere! It seems that it is adding a `using Root` somewhere automatically?

**N.B.** For now we have fixed it by settings `using SecurityEntity = Root.Entities.Security`

Comment: Why do you have a class named as a namespace of another library? Something is very wrong there

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Legacy code, one was created completely separately to the other. `Security` library was created for shared security helpers, `Security` entity is representing a financial security, and they have both been used in multiple (10-40) projects each, but I am guessing never together until now?

Comment: `Root.GUI` is under the namespace `Root`, so `Root` is automatically included. When you include `Root.Entities` you have a class named `Security` and a namespace named `Security` at the root level, what causes a conflict and the compiler doesn't knows if you're refering to the namespace or to the class.

Comment: @Gusman, That is what I assumed is happening, question is why is it importing `Root` automatically even when the "Default" namespace is `Root.Gui`. I would understand it to include `Root.Gui` but not every other namesapce underneath it! Otherwise in same line of thinking, why does `using System.X` not automatically import `System` root namespace?

Comment: @MichalCiechan That's because your main namespace is under another namespace, is not the same to live under than importing, that's why importing `System.XXX` does not import automatically `System`, but if you create something under `System.Whatever` then `System` will be automatically included. The idea here is if you create a new namespace under another namespace is because that root namespace contains code needed by the child namespace.

Comment: @Gusman interesting hypothesis :-)

Comment: @MichalCiechan Not an hypothesis, here you can see the info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces

Comment: @Gusman I would argue the the following excerpt: `if a type named Alias were to subsequently be introduced, Alias. would bind to that type instead. Using Alias::Exception insures that Alias is treated as a namespace alias and not mistaken for a type.` would suggest otherwise, that it should use the type over the namespace! Still seems wrong that just adding a reference to a dll breaks every file that uses `Root.Entities.Security`, even though they don't care/use `Root.Security`

Comment: Adding a reference will not break anything unless your code resides under the same root namespace and you have a class with the same name as an existing namespace.

Comment: @Gusman But the code resides under a different sub namespace, they do share the same 'Root'. My expectation is that having  using at the top of a file, should scope that using to that file, and override the Alias `Security`, exactly the same way as if it was inside the namespace (as there is only 1 namespace in the file), See Option 2 of Marc Gravell's answer

Comment: On version 2 you still will have two `Security` names on scope, is the exact same case.

Comment: @Gusman But as it has a using outside of the global namespace (inside `Root.Gui`), the `Root.Entities.Security` takes precedence, which is the same what I would expect with the outer. I would expect there to be a 'File' scope namespace scope,(like a hidden `namespace File_<Path> { ... }` for compilation scope resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain the "why?" - and I can repro it, but a few *workarounds*:

Option 1: fully qualify the type:

```
var security = new Root.Entities.Security();
```

Option 2: move your `using` directive *inside* the namespace declaration:

```
namespace Root.Gui
{
    using Root.Entities;
    public class Main
    {
        public Main()
        {
            // The following causes an error 
            // if Root.Security is add as a reference to the project.
            // even without adding `using Root.Security`
            var security = new Security();
        }
    }
}
```

I was slightly surprised that the `using` alias approach **does not** fix it:

```
using Security = Root.Entities.Security;
```

But you can cheat with Option 3:

```
using SecurityRenamed = Root.Entities.Security;
...
var security = new SecurityRenamed();
```

Comment: So now the question is, what is less of a hack, Option 2, `using ` inside namespace or Option 3 (and yeah we tried `using Security = ` but that failed). Option1 is just too ugly, as its mainly used as a generic parameter, which is long a obfuscated enough!

Comment: @MichalCiechan I only just noticed that you already had option 3 at the bottom of the question; so ... your call really; personally I hate using directives that aren't at the top of the code file, but : your code, not mine :)